# Our website is not resolving from our LAN because of LAN DNS configuration

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, website, fqdn

We have a LAN/WAN network with a Windows domain name (ourcompanyweb.org) that matches our website url (http://ourcompanyweb.org) which is hosted externally.  When I ping our website (of the same name) it returns the IP address of the local domain controller server instead of the website IP address.  Subsequently, user on the LAN/WAN cannot access the website.  What steps can I take to resolve this? Can I add a record in the DNS server that will forward the client computers to the external website? Accessing the website from outside our LAN works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a record in your internal DNS server that points to your website hosted on the Internet so when users hit your website URL they can be redirected to the actual public IP address. Make sure the name contains www.ourcompanyweb.org so it can be specific.

Comment: I added the record but also discovered that there were two other incorrect records for www so the resolution was still hinky until I deleted the old records.   The problem start when the webhost for the website changed ip's .